# How exactly is your software upgraded in Darwinia?

Tags: darwinia

I'm almost at Biosphere but my weapons are all on level 1, except my lasers. I don't know how I can get better grenades or rockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open up the task manager to select a squad or launch a program, there are two other panes to that window. One is mission objectives and the other is research.  You can choose to upgrade grenades and rockets there, although this only really improves their range.

That said, I kinda doubt you went through 80% of the gane not noticing that. You should know research is limited. It does build over time, but is capped depending on your progress through the game (heard specifically that every control tower you reprogram raises the cap, but don't know for sure). So if you've already maxed other functions, you may not have enough left for your rockets.

Comment: Concerning the cap - there are two separate mechanics at work. Each control tower you capture gives you 22 research points. These points are then spent over time on the reaserch you choose - v2 costs 50, v3 100, v4 200.

Comment: that is awfully specific, thanks radhil. thank your for your answers.